# Como fazer Ckeditor ser obrigatório o preenchimento como um atributo required

Tags: html, ckeditor

Não consigo fazer o ckeditor se comportar como um campo input ou textarea com required

```html
<textarea data-toggle="tooltip" maxlenfth="200" data-maxlen="200" class="form-control" rows="2" id="cumprimentos" name="cumprimentos" required>
</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
  CKEDITOR.replace('cumprimentos', {
    toolbar: [],
    height: 110,
    contentsCss: 'body {overflow:hidden;  font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, "Trebuchet MS", "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";font-size: 13px;color:#333;}',
    enterMode: Number(2),
    extraPlugins: 'forms',
    extraPlugins: 'html5validation',
    extraPlugins: 'wordcount',

    wordcount: {
      showWordCount: false,
      showParagraphs: false,
      showCharCount: true,
      maxCharCount: 200,
    }

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Qual versão vc está usando?

Comment: Ckeditor 4.12.1

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você tem que atribuir o plugin a uma variável:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('cumprimentos', {...
```

Veja que agora a instância do CKEditor tem um nome, `editor`.

Em seguida você usa o evento `required` do editor. Se o campo estiver vazio, irá disparar o `alert` e cancelar o envio do formulário:

```
editor.on('required', function(e){
    alert("preencha o campo");
    e.cancel();
});
```

Comment: Mas, Sam, mesmo assim o form é submitado e dá erro. Apesar de ter dado o alert.

Comment: Na verdade o input submit do formulário fica disable depois do alert.

Answer (score 1):

Veja o exemplo funcional em

https://jsfiddle.net/jorgercosta/306gfwy5/10/

Utilizando o evento 'required'